# Marklogic DLS service preserve specific version

Tags: marklogic

I am using MarkLogic DLS services to keep last two latest version of XML files.

```
My XML file has status:
`Draft, Withdrawn, and Published.`
```

User may change XML status any time, many time, from existing status to any other defined status. In our application, we have one search system where user can perform search on 'Published' video only. We want searching on all published videos, last published XML.

There is one another window in our application where we are getting all latest version of XML file and taking our actions.

The main problem, we are keeping two latest version only, skipping our last published XML.

Is there any way by which I can retain my published version history through Retention Rule?
Or any other way to keep them available while searching?

Please help, share your suggestions and views.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way do do this would be to tag the published versions with a collection, and then add a retention rule that has a query for that collection.